# ¿como podria mostrar un item de otro array que esta la misma posicion en paralelo?

Tags: java, android, array, studio

estoy intentando mostrar un item de un segundo array que esta en paralelo con el primer array. El tema es que estoy usando un autocompletetextview y que al seleccionar un item me muestre en un toast el item del segundo array que se encuentra paralelamente igual con respecto a la posicion. Por ejemplo, si seleccciono "java" me tiene que mostrar en el toast "puesto java" pero no logro conseguir porque me muestra otro item..

```
ArrayList <String> lenguajes = new ArrayList<String>();
        lenguajes.add("c");
        lenguajes.add("c++");
        lenguajes.add("java");
        lenguajes.add("net");
        lenguajes.add("iphone");
        lenguajes.add("android");
        lenguajes.add("aspnet");

        final ArrayList<String>respuesta=new ArrayList<String>();
        respuesta.add("puesto c");
        respuesta.add("puesto c++");
        respuesta.add("puesto java");
        respuesta.add("puesto net");
        respuesta.add("puesto iphone");
        respuesta.add("puesto android");
        respuesta.add("puesto aspnet");

        ArrayAdapter<String>adapterlenguaje=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,lenguajes);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapterrespuest=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,respuesta);

        AutoCompleteTextView actv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocompleedit);

        actv.setThreshold(1); //el actv se activara al poner una letra
        actv.setAdapter(adapterlenguaje);
        actv.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "respuesta paralela "+respuesta.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema aqui es que usando el AutocompleteTextView ya no puedes referenciarlos por la posicion (indice), te sugiero realizar un metodo para buscar la coincidencia por el texto.

Realiza un metodo para obtener esta coincidencia que recibe el lenguaje y el ArrayList conteniendo las respuestas:

```
private static String buscaRespuesta(String lenguaje, ArrayList<String> respuesta){        
    for(String s : respuesta){
        if(s.endsWith(lenguaje)){
            return s;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

y obten entonces la respuesta usando el metodo anterior:

```
    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "respuesta paralela "+buscaRespuesta(lenguajes.get(position),respuesta), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```